# Notification.requestPermission().then() always return Promise object instead of resolved reject value in console

Tags: browser, progressive-web-apps

executed following code in the console

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
    console.log('Notification permission status:', status);
});
```

in Chrome *v 61*

return

`Notification permission status: "granted"`

if already given otherwise pop-up appears near the left side of the address bar with Allow and Block option.

Although after several attempts then chrome also stop displaying the pop-up and gives information to the user in console.

and return

```
Notification permission status: "denied"
```

with message

> Notifications permission has been blocked as the user has dismissed
>   the permission prompt several times. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6443143280984064 for more
>   information.

BUT

in Firefox developer Edition *v 57*

return Promise object as below

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

why am I not getting the console message and neither does pop-up appears.

So my question is do I need to configure something in firefox?

or I am lacking something.

Note: I have tried both variations of [requestPermission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission) function suggested on MDN.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704771). Clearing browsing data will clear the block. Here's an additional [forum](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/115) which might also help.

Comment: I want to know why firefox doesn't invoke the notification pop-up while chrome does so.

Answer (score 1):

Promises and callbacks are executed asynchronously. What you see when you run this if Firefox is the temporary return value of the promise that the console.log will get executed in the future. The console.log is not however getting executed yet.

```
>> Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { console.log(permission); });
← Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

Basically what you see is working as intended. It's similar to doing something like this:

```
>> let thing = Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { console.log(permission); });
   console.log(thing);
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
← undefined
granted
```

The `console.log(thing)` is logging the promise that work will happen in the future but the permission grant and the `console.log(permission)` has not been executed yet.

Also the `Notification.requestPermission(callback);` format has been deprecated and should not be used.